# How to ignore the non-exist values while fetching results from database

Tags: sql

I have two separate tables `issuesLog` and `resolutionLog`. The latter table contains resolutions for the individual issues in *`issuesLog`*. So I am trying to make a joint table with the above fields in it and separate out the resolved issues from the unresolved ones. With the SQL query below, I don't get any results back from the database although there are a lot of unresolved issues but the problem is, `resolution` doesn't have/generate a default value to every corresponding `issueID`.So those unresolved issues don't even have null values or records in `resolutionLog` table and this is accusing with no results coming back from the database. Any ideas of how to get round that ?

```
SELECT issuesLog.fullName,issuesLog.issueID,resolutionLog.resolution
FROM issuesLog
INNER JOIN resolutionLog ON issuesLog.issueID= resolutionLog.issueID
where resolution is null
```

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want issues that are NOT in the resolution log.  If so, this should do what you want:

```
SELECT il.*
FROM issuesLog il
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM resolutionLog rl
                  WHERE il.issueID = rl.issueID
                 );
```

I see no reason to return a non-existent resolution, so `resolution` is not included in the result set.

Comment: I'm interested in the other data that comes with the unresolved issues. i.e fullName of the user as an example

Comment: @KhaledSalem . . . That should be in the issues log.